# In Lua, how can I know if a table contains a class function?

Tags: lua

Say I declare a lua function using the : operator like so:

```
function ClassName:myFunc( stuff )
    --do stuff
end
```

And then say I store that function in a table like so:

```
someTable = {
    ClassName.myFunc,
    someGlobalFunc,
}
```

And then, say I have another function that goes through the table and attempts to call the given functions.

```
function ClassName:callStuffInThisTable(table)
    -- I go through the table, which might be someTable above, and call all the functions
end
```

My question is, how do I know if a function in the table is owned by ClassName, so that I can call it using self?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you wanting/needing to call all of the functions in a given table, that you can't also mandate that all of those functions either *all* be class methods or *all* be bare functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't. At least, Lua isn't going to tell you.

`function ClassName:myFunc( stuff )` is just syntactic sugar as far as Lua is concerned. It's no different from this: `ClassName.myFunc = function (self, stuff)`. The functions are equivalent.
Likewise for the : call syntax, `ClassName:myFunc(stuff)` is semantically equivalent to `ClassName.myFunc(ClassName, stuff)`.

It is up to *you* to know what your functions are and what they do. This requires coding discipline. If you have a list of functions that you need to call in a loop, then they should be designed to be called with the *same* parameters.

There are two ways to do this. One way is to make all of the functions "class functions":

```
someTable = {
    ClassName.myFunc,
    function(self, ...) return someGlobalFunc(...) end,
}
```

This way, the `self` parameter is ignored. Obviously, you could create a special function table object that has functions for inserting "global" functions into the table that will automatically generate the wrapper:

```
function insertFuncIntoTable(self, func)
  self[#self + 1] = function(self, ...) func(...) end
end

insertFuncIntoTable(someTable, someGlobalFunc)
```

Note: there is a difference between these, assuming "someGlobalFunc" is actually a member of the global table (rather than a `local`). This version will take the value that `_G["someGlobalFunc"]` *currently* has, just as your original code does. However, the first version takes the value that it has *at the time it is called*, which may be a different function from the one it was at the time `someTable` was created.

So this version is safer.

Alternatively, you can make it so that any "class functions" in the table are explicitly bound to an object instance:

```
someTable = {
    function(self, ...) ClassName.myFunc() end,
    function(self, ...) return someGlobalFunc(...) end,
}
```

BTW, in general, if you declare a function using `:` syntax, you're supposed to *use* that function that way, via `instance:myFunc(...)`. Obviously it's just a Lua function like any other, so you can do what you like. But misuse can make understanding what's going on harder.

Lua affords you a lot of power. But you're still required to exercise judgement and discipline when coding. Lua will not save you from yourself (entirely).

Comment: Thanks for the insight. The leap I was failing to make was that since functions are anonymous, their names don't have any meaning.

Ultimately what I'm trying to do is make a script that iterates through functions and parameters, waiting when necessary, and so I'm doing this:

    script = { 
    { func, { params } },
    }

Ideally though I'd have user functions and pre-implemented functions. I can easily pass a self object, I was just trying to be clever.

Answer (score 0):

One way to tell if the function is "owned" by ClassName would be to scan and check.

```
ClassName = {}
function ClassName:fn(self) ... end

t = { function() ... end , ClassName.fn() }

function has_value( klass, value )
  for k,v in pairs(klass) do
    if v==value then return true
  end
  return false

function ClassName:callStuffInThisTable(table)
  for k,v in pairs(table) do
    if has_value(ClassName, v) then
      v(self)
    else
      v()
    end
  end
end
```

This has O(n^2) behaviour though due to the table scan. We can reduce this to O(n log(n)) ) by using the functions in ClassName as a new table

```
function ClassName:callStuffInThisTable(table)
  local t = {}
  for k,v in pairs(ClassName) do
    t[v] = 1
  end

  for k,v in pairs(table) do
    if t[v]==1 then
      v(self)
    else
      v()
    end
  end
end
```